# How access dial pad during the call?

Tags: android

I am working on conference manager application .I am using ACTION_CALL function for making the call and ACTION_DIAL for dialing number.But the call is going separate and the dial action is separate.Can anyone help me?here is my code

private void call(int profileid) {

```
    ProfileDo profile = adapter.getProfile(profileid);

    int stepCount = 0;
    long previousStepDelay = 0;
    for (StepDO step : profile.getSteps()) {
        Intent callIntent;

        String url = "tel:" + step.getValue();
        stepCount++;
        if (stepCount == 1) {

            callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(callIntent);

        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(previousStepDelay * 1000);
                System.out.println("hai");

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));

            startActivity(callIntent);

        }
        previousStepDelay = step.getDelay();

    }
}
```

}